# Weights in BCEWithLogitsLoss

Tags: pytorch, multilabel-classification, downsampling, imbalanced-data

I am facing an issue in a multi label, multi class classification task. I have a dataset of size 33000, each samples containing 104 classes. I split the dataset in 16500 samples with labels such as [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, …], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, …], [1, 0, 0, 0] (each label has at least one element 1 in it) and 16500 labels such as [0, 0, 0, …], [0, 0, 0, …] (all elements in all labels are 0). When calculating the pos_count for each class, the number pos_count_0 for class 0 is how many of 1 appear in the first position of each label in my dataset. For class 1, pos_count_1 the number of 1 in the second position and so on. And after that, the pos_weight of class 0 is (33000-pos_count_0)/pos_count_0, pos_weight of class 1 is (33000-pos_count_1)/pos_count_1 ? I am a little bit confused how neg_count and pos_count for a class are calculated.